# How can I make a class extend a specific instance of another class?

Tags: javascript, class, parameters, super, extends

As an example: Here are two classes, Entity and Character. Entity makes an object on a game map, and it has rest parameters to set where you can interact with it.

```
class Entity {
  constructor(sprite, pos, func, ...intcoords) {
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.func = func;
    move(pos, ...intcoords);
  }

  move(pos, ...intcoords) {
    this.y = pos[0]; this.x = pos[1];
    this.sprite = drawImg(this.sprite, this.y, this.x);
    for (let i in intcoords) {
      // process coordinates that should execute this.func: [y, x], [y, x]...
    }
  }
}
```

Meanwhile, Character makes an object that is able to talk with a pre-defined template.

```
class Character {
  constructor(name, talkimg = name + "webp", talkpos = [70, 20], talkflip = false) {
    this.name = name; this.talkimg = talkimg;
    this.talkpos = talkpos; this.talkflip = talkflip;
  }

  async talk(...strings) {
    speechSet(this.name, this.talkimg, this.talkpos, this.talkflip);
    await speech(...strings);
  }
}
```

In reality, characters will be activated because of a matching entity. So I believe the cleanest and most logical thing to do is have Character extend Entity. That way, I could have a single object like `ben` that I could call both `ben.move()` and `ben.talk()` with.

However, this would require using 7 parameters for Character, and sacrificing either default or rest parameters, which sucks. I could do it, and it would work, but it would suck and I would hate it. Ideally, I could define these parameters separately while still having a single object. I believe the best way would be if I could make an Entity separately, and then make that instance the super of a new Character.

One idea I had was making a single parameter at the beginning of Character, which could be passed an instance of Entity, and I could use that when declaring `super()`. That would allow me to define it this way and save it to a single variable:

```
ben = new Character(
  new Entity("ben.webp", [10, 6], benEvent, [9, 6], [9, 5]), 
  "Ben", "ben-angry.webp", [60, 30]);
```

The problem is that this creates and draws a new Entity, and then a duplicate is created inside Character. That's not going to work. Even if it didn't do that, Entity would have to save every parameter passed into it as a unique variable (which isn't used for any other purpose), then Character must reference those individually. That doesn't suck as bad, but I'd still prefer if I didn't do that.

Comment: Use a single argument, a destructured object with default properties

Comment: The thing you must decide is whether Character *is a kind of* Entity.  A strong clue that it is not is that constructors' params do not overlap.  Perhaps one has a reference to the other, or perhaps some other object keeps pairs of them together.